# Hide and show dropdownlist item in gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I want my dropdown list gridview to do not display have the same list item except for the "Please Select".
My dropdown is in gridview and the list item is in the code behind.
For example if 1 is selected all the dropdown list item should have not 1 in there selection until the 1 is selection is change.

Here is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvAcadSelec" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="acad_Id"
    DataSourceID="srcAcademy"
    OnRowDataBound="gdvAcadSelec_RowDataBound"
    CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered"
    EnableViewState="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="acad_Id" HeaderText="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="acad_name" HeaderText="Academy" />


        <%--            <asp:BoundField DataField="stud_id" HeaderText="stud_id"  />--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Choice">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPref" class="ddlSelect form-control form-control-lg" runat="server">
                    
                </asp:DropDownList>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void gdvAcadSelec_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Find the DropDownList in the Row
            DropDownList ddlCountries = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlPref") as DropDownList);
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("1"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("2"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem("3"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(4, new ListItem("4"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(5, new ListItem("5"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(6, new ListItem("6"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(7, new ListItem("7"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(8, new ListItem("8"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(9, new ListItem("9"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(10, new ListItem("10"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(11, new ListItem("11"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(12, new ListItem("12"));
            ddlCountries.Items.Insert(13, new ListItem("13"));
        }

    }
```

Till now I have got a jquery code but it is impacting the "Please Select" item and is showing the selected item when the other dropdown list select another item.

Here is the code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ddlSelect').on('change', function () {
            var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
            $('.ddlSelect').find('option').show();
            $('.ddlSelect').not(this).find('option:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
        });
    });
```

I am totally stuck with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

first, our markup:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="Ghotels" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" Width="50%" OnRowDataBound="Ghotels_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"        />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"          />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"        />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"    />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rank">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboRank" runat="server"
                            DataTextField ="Text"
                            DataValueField ="Value"
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboRank_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            >
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>


        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server"
            OnClick="cmdSave_Click"
            Text="Save Changes to database" 
            CssClass="btn"/>
```

Ok, now our code to load grid:

```
   List<ListItem> MyRankList = new List<ListItem>();
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadRank();
            LoadData();
            LoadGrid();
            Session["rstData"] = rstData;
        }
        else
        {
            rstData = (DataTable)Session["rstData"];
        }
    }

    void LoadRank()
    {
        MyRankList = new List<ListItem>();
        MyRankList.Add(new ListItem("Please Select", "0"));

        for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++)
        {
            MyRankList.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
        }
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT TOP 13 * from tblHotels ORDER BY ID";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
    }
    void LoadGrid()
    {
        Ghotels.DataSource = null;
        Ghotels.DataSource = rstData;
        Ghotels.DataBind();
    }
```

And we now have this:

[image]

So, the only part left, is as we bind each row, we setup combo box to the database value AND THEN REMOVE that choice from the list, right?

So, we have this:

```
   protected void Ghotels_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList cboRank = e.Row.FindControl("cboRank") as DropDownList;
            
            cboRank.DataSource = MyRankList;
            cboRank.DataBind();

            // get current rank row value
            int? intRank = rstData.Rows[e.Row.DataItemIndex]["Ranking"] as int?;
            if (intRank == null)
                intRank = 0;

            if (intRank != 0)
            {
                // set combo to rank
                cboRank.SelectedValue = intRank.ToString();

                // remove this item from choice list
                // becuase some items already removed, we can't
                // use simple index anymore, since index num <> postion anymore

                var itemToRemove = MyRankList.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Value == intRank.ToString());
                if (itemToRemove != null)
                    MyRankList.Remove(itemToRemove);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, if user does select a combo box, then we need to update that list, right?

So, note how we have auto post back for the combo, and then we have this event code:

```
   protected void cboRank_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList cboRank = sender as DropDownList;
        GridViewRow gRow = cboRank.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        string strRank = cboRank.SelectedItem.Value;
        // set our data table to this choice
        rstData.Rows[gRow.DataItemIndex]["Ranking"] = strRank;

        // now reflect this change in grid
        LoadRank();
        LoadGrid();
    }
```

Note how easy the above is - all we do is update table, and then run the same orgional code and process again.

And of course, we need a button to send all the changes back to the database, right?

So that code (the save button below the grid) is this:

```
   protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // send changes back to database
        string strSQL = "SELECT * from tblHotels where ID = 0";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(rstData);
            }
        }
    }
```

Remember, if you change a existing combo to different? Well that will work, since we  re-load the full list, re-bind, and the rebind will re-run the remove code.
This way, we don't have any complex logic to put un-used values back into the drop list.

And in fact, if you select "0" for a exiting choice - that number will be put back in the list also.